# Change the Frame of Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

The current python code with plotly in the google colab results in Picture A.

What I want is Picture B (the frame as the x-axis and y-axis are black lines).

[image]

```
# x and y given as array_like objects
import plotly.express as px

df = df_final
df["Optimality"] = df["Optimality"].astype(str)
fig = px.scatter(df, x="P2", y="C2", color = "Optimality", width=800, height=800, color_discrete_sequence=["white", "green"], category_orders={"Optimality": ["0", "1"]})

fig.update_layout(
    title={
        'text': r'$\textit{Backward(0) Sequence}$',  # Use LaTeX formatting for title
        'y':0.95,  # Adjust the y position of the title
        'x':0.5,  # Center the title horizontally
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top',
        'font': dict(family='Times New Roman',size=30, color="Black")  # Set the font size of the title
    },
    xaxis=dict(title=dict(text="Optimality", font=dict(family="Times New Roman", size=30))),  # Set the font size of the x-axis label
    xaxis_title=r'$p_2$',  # Use LaTeX formatting for x-axis title
    yaxis_title=r'$c_2$',
    font=dict(family="Times New Roman", size=20, color="Black"),
    legend=dict(itemsizing="constant", font=dict(size=20),title=dict(text='Optimality', font=dict(family='Times New Roman', size=18))))


fig.show()
```

What should be adjusted in the code?

Comment: Try this: `fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True);fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', mirror=True)` Refer to [detail](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#mirroring-axis-lines).

Answer (score 0):

The main attributes for the layoyt of the figure you're looking for here to get your desired result are `xaxis`, `yaxis`, `paper_bgcolor` and `plot_bgcolor` with the following setup:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range = [0, 500],
                  yaxis_showline=True, yaxis_linewidth=2, yaxis_linecolor='black', yaxis_mirror=True,
                  xaxis_range = [0,500],
                  xaxis_showline=True, xaxis_linewidth=2, xaxis_linecolor='black', xaxis_mirror=True,
                  paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  paper_bgcolor='white',
                  plot_bgcolor='white'
                  )
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=0, y0=0, x1=300, y1=200,
    line=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
    fillcolor="green",
)

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=150, y0=50, x1=500, y1=500,
    line=dict(color="rgba(0,0,0,0)"),
    fillcolor="green",
)

fig.update_layout(yaxis_range = [0, 500],
                  yaxis_showline=True, yaxis_linewidth=2, yaxis_linecolor='black', yaxis_mirror=True,
                  xaxis_range = [0,500],
                  xaxis_showline=True, xaxis_linewidth=2, xaxis_linecolor='black', xaxis_mirror=True,
                  paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  paper_bgcolor='white',
                  plot_bgcolor='white'
                  )

fig.show()
```